# django test the correct template used: with self.assertTemplateUsed()

Tags: django, testing

I used to see the following tests in Django:

```
with self.assertTemplateUsed('<someTemplate>'):
    response = self.client.get('<someURL>')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Question:

Since we have already had the `with` part, is it necessary to test the `status_code`? In other words, is the final statement redundant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always a good idea to test `status_code` even with views rendering templates.

Django gives you ability to pass status code of your wish while rendering templates.

Both [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) and [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) take `status` as keyword argument so that you can render the page with a status code you think is appropriate for the view.

Thus, you can render templates with any response status code not just `200`. This gives you a reason to test status code while using `assertTemplateUsed` as a context manager.

Answer (score 2):

It's not redundant if you app might send different responses status using the same template. In general cases, using the `assertTemplateUsed` it's just fine.